# The tubes for Flappy Bird don't work proprely

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to create a videogame (Flappy Bird) and now I'm stucked because the tubes don't work proprely. Here's the program:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

# Width = x, height = y 
width, height = 800, 600
run = True

# Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# Variables
x = 150
y = 100

base_x = 0
base_y = 475
base_width = 800

velocity_forward = 8
FPS = 50

def tubes():
    tubes = []
    tubes.append(tubes_class())

    for t in tubes:
        t.go_and_draw()

def rectangles():
    global velocity_forward, base_x, floor, player
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), pygame.Rect(x,y,30,30))
    
    base_x += velocity_forward    
    floor = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), pygame.Rect(0,500,900+base_x,10))

tubedown = pygame.image.load('tubo.png')
tubeup = pygame.transform.flip(tubedown, False, True)

class tubes_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 300
        self.y = random.randint(-75,150)

    def go_and_draw(self):
        self.x -= velocity_forward
        screen.blit(tubedown, (self.x,self.y+210))
        screen.blit(tubeup, (self.x,self.y-210))

# Main loop
run = True
while run:

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    
    # Fall
    y += 5

    # Handle movement
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 12

    rectangles()

    tubes()
    
    # Game over
    if pygame.Rect.colliderect(floor,player) == True:
        run = False

    if y == 0:
        run = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

The tubes should move towards the bird (I'm using a square), but I can't make them to do so and they just go up and down really fast. I can't find the problem, can somebody help me?

Comment: It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). `pygame.display.update()` has to be called in the application loop, not just in case of `if y == 0:`

Answer (score 0):

Your tube has two coordinates `x` and `y`, what you actually do is when you call `tubes` function you create single instace of `tube`. Then the function calls `go_and_draw` which changes the `x` coordinate by 8. But since you use it only once and the blit is used after you change the `x` there is actually no movement at all.

Comment: Can you change the code? (I dodn't understand)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `pygame.time.Clock()` object before the applicaition loop:

<s>`pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)`</s>

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # [...]
```

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time.
The method computes the time passed since the last call. Therefore the last time of the method call is stred in the `pygame.time.Clock()` object. If a new object is constantly being created in the application loop, no time can be stored and the frames per second cannot be controlled correctly.

Comment: Actually the output is the same

Comment: @Programmer Anyway it is a bug in your application.